# request.data is different in runserver and uwsgi

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm sending a post request to server. I use runserver to test and I use uwsgi inside docker as well.
When I use request.data to serialize the object, it works fine in run server. The output data is like
[enter image description here][1]

But when I use uwsgi in docker-omposer up and use the same request.data it is different. This causes it not to store in DB.
[enter image description here][2]

Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFVpz.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6sIf.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get the json exactly parsed at the request to be received when called request.data